# Testing with a supertest

Tags: java, testing, superclass

I'm new to java and i need to make 2 test classes with a SuperTest class.
Right now i've got the following:

This is my supertest class. What i want to do here is putting the results in it should give.

```
public class SuperTest
{
public void test (Zoeker zoeker)
{
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] {21, 27}, zoeker.zoek("AC"));
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] {5, 9}, zoeker.zoek("GC"));
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] {0, 11, 15}, zoeker.zoek("AT"));
}
}
```

This is one of my test classes. Here i would like to make an object to test the Algoritme1 class using the method of the supertest class.

```
public class Test1 extends SuperTest
{

Zoeker zoeker;

@Test
public void Algoritme1()
{
    SuperTest algoritm1 = new SuperTest();
    algoritm1.test(zoeker);      

}

}
```

At the moment i get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

You get a null pointer exception because you defined a field named zoeker but did not initialize it. Differently from C, Java variables are all references (equivalent of pointers in C) so zoeker in Test1 is null: it does not represent an object but an empty container for that object, in laymen terms.

I'm not very sure what you're trying to achieve, but the easiest fix is adding:

`zoeker = new Zoeker();`

in Algoritme1(), which will prevent the NullPointerException.